# From String to Object

Tags: javascript

I need to go from

```
'IsEditOnly=False;IsLastFieldInRow=False;IsReadOnly=False;Title=bedrijfStandaard;Width=100'
```

to something like

```
{IsEditOnly: false, Title: 'bedrijfStandaard'}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code that you think might work and we'll tell you why it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s='IsEditOnly=False;IsLastFieldInRow=False;IsReadOnly=False;Title=bedrijfStandaard;Width=100';
s=s.replace(/=/g, ':"');
s=s.replace(/;/g, '",');
s+='"';
eval('var obj={'+s+'}');
alert(obj.Width);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w1yq4vtc/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var queryToObject = function(s){
    var
    i = 0,
    retObj = {},
    pair = null,
    qArr = s.split(';');

    for (; i < qArr.length; i++){
        pair = qArr[i].split('=');
        retObj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    };

    return retObj;
};

var query = 'IsEditOnly=False;IsLastFieldInRow=False;IsReadOnly=False;Title=bedrijfStandaard;Width=100';
console.dir(queryToObject(query));
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/scrorjep/)**